# asp-validation-summary does not show error in ModelOnly mode

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I have noticed that errors are not shown when `asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly"`. When I change value to `asp-validation-summary="All"` it works fine.

Maybe it is because I am using `ValidationAttribute`?
Here is code sample:

```
@page "/pages/test"
@model TestPageModel
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
@addTagHelper *, WebApp
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages
@using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link href="~/lib/twitter-bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
    <div class="m-2">
        <h5 class="bg-primary text-white text-center p-2">TEST</h5>
        <form asp-page="TestPage" method="post">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Name</label>
                <div><span asp-validation-for="TestModel.Value" class="text-danger"></span></div>
                <input class="form-control" asp-for="TestModel.Value" />
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>

@functions{
    public class TestPageModel : PageModel
    {
        [BindProperty]
        public TestModel TestModel { get; set; } = new TestModel();

        public Task OnGetAsync()
        {

            TestModel = new TestModel() { Value = "Some value" };
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        public IActionResult OnPost() => Page();
    }

    public class TestValidationAttribute : ValidationAttribute
    {
        protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object? value, ValidationContext validationContext)
        {
            return new ValidationResult("Something is wrong");
        }
    }

    [TestValidation]
    public class TestModel
    {
        public string Value { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    }
}
```

Could you please help me find what is missing?

Comment: ValidationSummary.All will display both property and model level validations messages.ValidationSummary.ModelOnly will display only validation messages that apply to the model level.

Comment: @YiyiYou Look, I decorated class with my validation attribute, not property. It should be model validation message, right? How come it is not visible?

Comment: Validation attribute helps you specify validation rules for model properties,so it is used for model properties rather than the model.You can refer to the official [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-6.0).